# spring boot external property file update

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have external property file. I am loading that property file at the initialization level.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class URITemplate
{

    private String urlOne;

    private String urlTwo;
}
```

Now At run time I want to update this property file and reload it in spring boot application..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update configuration of SpringBoot application at runtime without reloading whole ApplicationContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365874/how-to-update-configuration-of-springboot-application-at-runtime-without-reloadi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better configure properties for compilation (before running) and not change them on runtime. Generally, the idea behind properties is to have them static. 
Following this [article](http://www.summa.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring), the best approach is to think what you use the properties for and then consider changing those into variables - which are mutable at runtime.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks it was nice article